# Changing **array + a to *array[a]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What my program does is it finds 2 numbers of an array that are closest to the average, one is bigger, one is smaller. It works fine, however I need to change for example `**array+a` to `*array[a]`.

However, when I load the program, it crashes after I input the numbers. If I try to print `*array[0]`, `*array[1]`, etc. it works fine. When I try to print or just do something with `*array[a]`, `*array[b]`, it crashes. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int  input    (int *t, int *array[]);
void calculation (int *array[], int *t, int *x, int *y);
void output   (int *x, int *y);

int main()
{
    int *array, t, x, y;
    input (&t, &array);
    calculation (&array, &t, &x, &y);
    output (&x, &y);
    return 0;
}
int input (int *t, int *array[])
{   int n, *ptr;
    printf ("How big is the array?");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    ptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int k;
    printf ("Enter the numbers:");
    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
    {   scanf ("%d", ptr + k);
    }
    *t=n;
    *array=ptr;
    return 0;
}
void calculation (int *array[], int *t, int *x, int *y)
{   float sum=0, avg;
    int min, max; 
    int more, less; 
    int a, b, c;  
    for (a=0; a<(*t); a++)
        {sum=sum+ **array + a;
        }
    avg=sum/(*t);
    min= *array[0];
    max= *array[0];

    for (b=0; b<(*t); b++)
    {       if (max < (**array + b)) max=(**array + b);
            if (min > (**array + b)) min=(**array + b);
    }
    more=max;
    less=min;
    for (c=0; c<(*t); c++)
    {   if (((**array + c) < avg) && ((**array + c) > less)) less=(**array + c);
        if (((**array + c) > avg) && ((**array + c) < more)) more=(**array + c);
    }
    *x=less;
    *y=more;
}

void output (int *x, int *y)
{       printf("Number that is less than the average:%d\n", *x);
        printf("Number that is more than the average:%d\n", *y);
}
```

Comment: `**array+a` to `(*array)[a]`

Comment: The declaration `int *array[]` says that `array` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. :)

Comment: I can't believe your code works correct as-is in the question. When I run it with '10 20 30` as input array, it outputs `Number that is less than the average:10  Number that is more than the average:12`. This: `sum=sum+ **array + a;` should almost certainly be: `sum=sum+ *(*array + a);`. You seem to expect one `*` to bind tighter than `+` but the other one not to...

Comment: (Note that `*(*array + a)` is equivalent to `(*array)[a]`. `**array + a` cannot be written in array notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to rethink your function prototypes a bit. It makes sense to pass a pointer to `array` to the `input()` function since you are allocating memory for it, and you want to be able to access it when you return. But you don't need to pass in the pointer to `int t`; instead, just return the value of `n`, and assign it to `t` in main.

There is no reason to pass a pointer to `array` to the function `calculation()`, since you are not changing the array allocation. You can also pass in the value of `t` from `main()`, since you only use this value in `calculation()`, but do not change it.

Similarly, the `output()` function only needs copies of `x` and `y`, since it does not change them.

The rule of thumb here is that you pass a pointer to a value into a function when you want to modify the value inside the function and have access to the modified value in the calling function. But you can also return a value instead of using a pointer to it.

These changes do not alter the functionality of your code, but they substantially improve its readability. You even get a sense of what is being modified in each function just by looking at the function prototypes. Well, the changes do alter the functionality in that your original `**array + a` was incorrect, and needed to be either `*(*array + a)` or `(*array)[a]`. But sorting that problem out should help you to appreciate the virtue of the simpler function prototypes. Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input(int *array[]);
void calculation(int array[], int t, int *x, int *y);
void output(int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
    int *array, t, x, y;

    t = input(&array);
    calculation(array, t, &x, &y);
    output(x, y);
    return 0;
}
int input(int *array[])
{   int n, *ptr;
    printf("How big is the array?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int k;
    printf("Enter the numbers:");
    for (k=0; k<n; k++)
    {   scanf("%d", ptr + k);
    }
    *array=ptr;
    return n;
}
void calculation(int array[], int t, int *x, int *y)
{   float sum=0, avg;
    int min, max; 
    int more, less; 
    int a, b, c;  
    for (a=0; a<t; a++)
    {sum=sum+ array[a];
    }
    avg=sum/t;
    min= array[0];
    max= array[0];

    for (b=0; b<t; b++)
    {       if (max < array[b]) max=array[b];
        if (min > array[b]) min=array[b];
    }
    more=max;
    less=min;
    for (c=0; c<t; c++)
    {   if ((array[c] < avg) && (array[c] > less)) less=array[c];
        if ((array[c] > avg) && (array[c] < more)) more=array[c];
    }
    *x=less;
    *y=more;
}

void output(int x, int y)
{       printf("Number that is less than the average:%d\n", x);
    printf("Number that is more than the average:%d\n", y);
}
```

Comment: Surely `*(*array + a)` (not `(**array + a)`) is equivalent to `(*array)[a]`. Or is my brain really not working right today?

Comment: I went so far as to test this; I'm fairly sure that OP's original program is not correct (despite their claim otherwise) and it is _not_ correct that `*(*array + a)` is equivalent to `**array + a`. You say that `**arr` points to the first element of the array, but in fact it _is_ the first element of the array - `*arr` points to the first element of the array - right? So `**arr + i` is actually the value of the first element in the array plus `i`, rather than the value of the `i`th element.

Comment: @davmac-- You are correct! I was scratching my head over this even as you sent the comment. My answer wasn't really about the equivalence of the expressions, so I didn't give that much thought. I did run the OPs program, and it seemed to work. But I just now tried with the values 3 1 4 1 5 9, and OPs version gave results 5 and 6! My version (which could still be wrong, because I only changed the function prototypes) gave the correct result of 3 and 4. Good catch.

Comment: @davmac-- I don't know how I missed your earlier comments to the OP. I will remove this silliness from my answer, and facepalm....

Comment: No problem - I thought I was going mad there for a bit, glad to find out that's not the case!

Answer (score 0):

Just like BLUEPIXY and Some programmer dude said, it's supposed to be (*array)[a]